# SharePoint 2016 - SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile() method not overwriting the file

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am creating **Custom Menu Item** in SharePoint 2016. A custom menu basically copies file from one location to another. I am using `SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyfile()` method with the parameters:

- context
- sourceURL
- destinationURL
- overwrite - (boolean true/false)

The last parameter is not affecting the functionality of the method, even if I remove and execute the method it works.

The issue here is that I am not able to overwrite a file which already exists in the destination.

Comment: What language do you use? Javascript or .NET CSOM? Can you provide example code, so web can see how you are using it?

Answer (score -1):

Hey i'm also facing similar issue , was trying to create a custom menu in Share-point 2016.
The custom menu and everything gets created and its also able to copy the files , its just we are not able to overwrite the existing file in the destination folder.

```
**SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context, source, destn);**
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                alert("The file was copied successfully");
                location.href = sourceLib;
            },
            function (s, a) {
                alert(a.get_message());
                location.href = sourceLib;
            }
        );
```

Here we can pass a flag to overwrite boolean value (true/false). But it doesn't quite affect the working of this method.
**SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context, source, destn,true);**
Context - is the context of the current page
source - is the source URL from where we need to copy the file i.e. xyz.com/test.txt
destn - is the destination URL from where we need to copy the file i.e. xyz.com/test.txt

Comment: Quick update on this one guys :
We tried the same piece of code on O365 (Sharepoint - online) , seems like sharepoint-2016 (On premises) might require some patching or updating the js files. So that the code works in sharepoint-2016.
Code-wise its good , its working on O365